# Open System Settings from a Service

Tags: android, android-service

I am writing a service to collect location readings while my application is running in the foreground.  In the `LocationListener`, I would like to use the `onProviderDisabled()` method to open a dialog telling the user that the location provider is disabled, and have a button on the dialog that will launch the system's location settings panel, allowing the user to enable the location provider if they choose.  If this was an activity, I would launch the system settings using `startActivityforResult()`, but I can only use `startActivity` from a service.

My question is this: is there a way I can open the settings from a service, and have this new activity close and return to my application after the user changes a setting?

**EDIT:**  What I'm trying to achieve is a `Service` running from the moment the application opens until it closes and collecting location readings, maintaining a best estimate of location for use in the application.  If the `LocationListener` within the service has `onProviderDisabled` called, I want this to cause a dialog to open that will give the user the option to go to the System Settings and enable location providers (or cancel and carry on, although some of the application's features won't work without location).  I agree that the perhaps the `Service` isn't the place to do the dialog/activity launch part as it is a background component with no UI, but I'm not sure where the code for this should go.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly..."**return to my application after the user changes a setting**". If you're dealing with just a `Service` then it will continue to run regardless of what the users sees / interacts with at the UI level.

Comment: `What I'm trying to achieve is a Service running from the moment the application opens until it closes and collecting location readings`  This sounds like Location needs to be in the Activity not a service.

Comment: Hi Dan, I'm not sure how I can have an activity running for the whole time the application is open, while the user is interacting with other activities? I just need a class that collects up location readings that other classes can use, and that has a lifetime that is as long as the application is open.  Also, I am extending `IntentService` so the location checking can be done in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the edit to your question and the comment to Sam's answer, I'd basically do a check in the Activity (or all Activities) of the app and launch the dialog and subsequent 'Settings' page from there (if the user chooses to go to Settings).

Basically, have the Service do what it needs to based on the current environment the main Activity encounters (provider disabled/enabled). If your Service will be running when there is no user front-end then have it compensate and reduce its 'duties' accordingly.

Also, in that scenario, Sam's idea of using a notification (which in turn could cause the Settings to be opened) is a good middle ground.

**EDIT** To explain a little further. Take something as simple as an email app. There are two aspects to this...

Firstly there's a UI - when the user opens their email app if 'the network' is disabled the user is told so with a dialog with the option to go to network settings to enable the network. Pressing BACK (from Settings) will return to the email app and it will attempt to download any new emails. If the user decides not to enable the network they can still view previously downloaded emails (similar to partial functionality in you situation).

Secondly there is a background service which periodically (every 15 mins, 30 mins, 1 hr etc) will attempt to download any new emails even if the UI is closed. If the network is disabled it will simply go to sleep (until next download time).

In theory if a user disables the network, the background email service 'could' provide a dialog or notification to say "You do realise I can't work now?"...this is kind of what you want to do BUT if the service has other things to do it can simply do those and ignore any network-related tasks. Next time the user fires up the Activity, they then get a dialog with the option to enable the network.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  Are you suggesting, for example, have a `boolean` flag in the `Service` that represents the is enabled/is not enabled state, and have a public method in the Service that an Activity can call to retrieve the flag's value, and then act accordingly, while the Service handles matters in its own way?

Comment: Thanks for the edit - yes I follow you now, and this approach is much better than what I was thinking of, thanks!

Comment: @Vicki D: Glad I could help - admittedly it's a tricky scenario but it gives you a different angle to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Service has the [ContextWrapper.startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) method which will open the desired Settings menu. The user will select what they would like to enable then touch back to return your Activity. Once back in your activity you can check [LocationManager.isProviderEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29). Unfortunately a service cannot take an Activity result.

Answer (score 0):

just curious. service may run even if the user is not seeing the screen, or even the screen may be turned off. is it a good idea, showing a dialog from the service.

anyway, since you know how to show an activity, in the onCreate fire the intent for the settings and finish it once you get to onActivityResult.

sure this is a simple hack.

**EDIT:** if you are not sure where it should go. the best i can think, and even seen in some apps is the **notification** area.

Comment: Good point about the service running with the user not seeing the screen, but this is (at least for the time being, I'm still playing around with things) a bound service that is started when the application is opened and stopped when it is closed.  If the user disables location services and then opens the application, the dialog will open fairly soon after.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry by 'it' I meant the code, not the message.  I have edited by question to make it clearer. The facebook app on my phone does something similar when I turn off network connections (opens a dialog with a link to the right settings activity), I thought it was a nice way of informing the user

Comment: as for me i would do in two places, in the activity and notification. we can show the dialog in the activity (when the use is seeing the screen) and in the notification area assuming the user is meddling with other things in the phone. mean while there are other options like viberator, LED's if you really want the attention of the user. Ofcourse with an option to the user to disable them.

Comment: as per Dan's comment. if you are not logging the locations even after closing the activity, you may even dont need a service. but if you are logging then my previous comment would make sense.